# Inappropriate comment?

Tags: discussion

I got a return comment from this member: former user no. 26880. It seems to be conspiracy theory type stuff. It seems possibly anti-Semitic to me.  I didn't know where to report this so I am reporting it here. Thank you.

Comment: Next to someone's comments there should be an arrow pointed up which lets you up vote the comment and under that is a flag which lets you flag the comment as either rude, unnecessary, or otherwise in need of a moderator's attention. Did you flag the comment in question as well as posting this?

Comment: No. I didn't know about this feature.

Comment: Should I go to it and try to do that?  It was on the question about fallacy and dictatorship of proletariat, in the comment section.

Comment: I've been here less than a week so I'm still learning. BTW I don't see the flag option you speak of. It seems like the only option I have is up vote.

Comment: Maybe it's something that comes with a certain level of reputation then, that would make more sense now that I think about it. Can you link me to the question please? If it looks egregious I will flag it

Comment: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/44943/what-logical-fallacy-is-dictatorship-of-the-proletariat-dictatorship

Comment: Yes, that is pretty egregious; I flagged the comment. That user has been involved in some low quality answers in the past (borderline what he posted in that comment) so I'm sure something will be done about it this time if he decides he isn't going to leave the site.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate your looking into it for me. Take care.

Comment: Are you on a mobile browser? Then the flag doesn't show.

Answer (score 2):

*Any* anti semitic comment, as any form of racism, is repulsive, and to be extremely disocuraged, and immediately reported to the moderators. For, of course, a heavy ban.

Conspiracy theories have their own stackexchange, I'm sure.

Comment: Conspiracy theories are sort of within skeptics.se purview (but this kind of thing is almost certainly unacceptable even there)